# Preventing "foo" from matching "foo-bar" with grep -w

Tags: regex, bash, perl, grep

I am using grep inside my Perl script and I am trying to grep the exact keyword that I am giving. The problem is that "-w" doesn't recognize the "-" symbol as a separator.

example:
Let's say that I have these two records:

```
A1BG    0.0767377011073753
A1BG-AS1    0.233775553296782
```

if I give
    grep -w "A1BG"
it returns both of them but I want only the exact one.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks in advance.

PS.

Here is my whole code.
The input file is a two-columns tab separated. So, I want to keep a unique value for each gene. In cases that I have more than one record, I calculate the average.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Find the average fc between common genes
sub avg {
my $total;
$total += $_ foreach @_;
   return $total / @_;
}

my @mykeys = `cat G13_T.txt| awk '{print \$1}'| sort -u`;
foreach (@mykeys)
{
    my @TSS = ();

    my $op1 = 0;

    my $key = $_;
    chomp($key);
    #print "$key\n";
    my $command = "cat G13_T.txt|grep -E '([[:space:]]|^)$key([[:space:]]|\$)'";
    #my $command = "cat Unique_Genes/G13_T.txt|grep -w $key";
    my @belongs= `$command`;
    chomp(@belongs);
    my $count = scalar(@belongs);
    if ($count == 1) {
            print "$belongs[0]\n";
    }
    else {
            for (my $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                    my @token = split('\t', $belongs[$i]);
                    my $lfc = $token[1];
                    push (@TSS, $lfc);
            }
            $op1 = avg(@TSS);
            print $key ."\t". $op1. "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show that code?

Comment: Try `grep -E '([[:space:]]|^)A1BG([[:space:]]|$)'`

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `-w`, rather than asking for a string terminated in whitespace explicitly? Or to use `grep` from a perl script at all, when this is *specifically the kind of thing perl is good at* doing internally?

Comment: Actually, `-w` *is* recognizing `-` as a word separator (logically) thus your dilemma. As Charles suggests, don't use `grep -w` to do the job.

Comment: To be clear, which characters are and are not considered word separators by grep is locale-dependent, so even if it works in one region or set of language settings, it won't work the same place everywhere. That's a problem universal to `grep -w`, making it a bad choice when you want to match anything other than words in the actively-configured locale.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks Charles but the way that the rest of the code is, it works fine. (apart from this file that includes the dash ids). I have a list of ids that I am taking it from a file and I am using grep to gather the duplicates in an array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, I think that it worked! :) Thank you

Comment: @Vasilis, "the way I have my code" -- that's circular reasoning. The whole argument is that your code would be better (more portable, reliable across different operating systems and locales, and better performance on account of avoiding process-startup overhead) written differently.

Comment: @zdim Yes, of course. Can I put it in the comments?

Comment: @Vasilis Well, I meant "edit" the question and add it there.

Comment: @Vasilis  It appears that you use system's `grep`, as an external command, out of a Perl program.  Seeing how exactly you do that normally helps people to help you out. (For one, it seems that you don't need to go out to the system at all.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  Are you sure that `$command` is correct -- that `cat` has nothing to do?  (Btw, you don't need `cat file | grep ...` -- can do `grep ... file`)

Comment: Can you confirm for me the objective of your code: (1) Gather phrases in the first column (like `A1BG`) from file `G13_T.txt` (the `awk` involving line) (2) Go through all these, and for each look for it in a file `Unique_Genes/G13_T.txt`.  If more than one are found compute average.  Is this what you do?

Comment: @zdim Sorry, my bad. ```cat``` command goes to the same file (edited the code). 
Yes, awk gathers all the unique phrases from the first column and then it searches the whole file. In cases of the more than one calculate the average.
Apart from the ```grep``` issue works fine but the truth is that it is quite slow, especially with large files.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So the repeated processing (after the `awk` line, in the loop over `@mykeys`) is only to see whether phrases from the first column come more than once?

Comment: "_quite slow, especially with large files_" -- right, it processes the whole file all over again for every single phrase. And it runs external commands each time (expensive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got clarifications in comments right, the objective is to find the average of values (second column) for unique names in the first column. Then there is no need for external tools.

Read the file line by line and add up values for each name. The name uniqueness is granted by using a hash, with names being keys. Along with this also track their counts

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %results;

while (<$fh>) {
    #my ($name, $value) = split /\t/;
    my ($name, $value) = split /\s+/;  # used for easier testing

    $results{$name}{value} += $value;
    ++$results{$name}{count};
}

foreach my $name (sort keys %results) { 
    $results{$name}{value} /= $results{$name}{count} 
        if $results{$name}{count} > 1;

    say "$name => $results{$name}{value}";
}
```

After the file is processed each accumulated value is divided by its count and overwritten by that, so by its average ([`/=`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) divides and assigns), if count `> 1` (as a small measure of efficiency).

If there is any use in knowing all values that were found for each name, then store them in an arrayref for each key instead of adding them

```
while (<$fh>) {
    #my ($name, $value) = split /\t/;
    my ($name, $value) = split /\s+/;  # used for easier testing

    push @{$results{$name}}, $value;
}
```

where now we don't need the count as it is given by the number of elements in the array(ref)

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

foreach my $name (sort keys %results) {
    say "$name => ", sum(@{$results{$name}}) / @{$results{$name}};
}
```

Note that a hash built this way needs memory comparable to the file size (or may even exceed it), since *all* values are stored.

This was tested using the shown two lines of sample data, repeated and changed in a file. The code does not test the input in any way, but expects the second field to always be a number.

Notice that there is no reason to ever step out of our program and use external commands.

Comment: Ok, this is an amazing approach! I wish I could think that way!
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Vasilis Glad you like it :).  It's worth noting and remembering, this is a good example of the great utility of a hash (dictionary) and one of its typical uses.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a POSIX ERE regex with `grep` like this:

```
grep -E '([[:space:]]|^)A1BG([[:space:]]|$)' file
```

To return matches (not matching lines) only:

```
grep -Eo '([[:space:]]|^)A1BG([[:space:]]|$)' file
```

**Details**

- `([[:space:]]|^)` - Group 1: a whitespace or start of line
- `A1BG` - a substring
- `([[:space:]]|$)` - Group 2: a whitespace or end of line